# クライアントサイドでメールドメインの存在チェックをする良い方法は？

Tags: javascript, java, sendmail

＜目的＞
新規会員登録のメールアドレス入力時に、入力間違えや不正登録を阻止するため

＜やりたいこと＞
ユーザーが入力したドメインが存在しているかチェックする機能を実装したい
※可能であればクライアントサイドで、リアルタイムに存在チェックをしたい

＜使用言語＞
Java、Javascript

＜調べたこと、参照したもの＞
▼PHPでのメールアドレス判定について
[PHPで文字列がメールアドレスか判定するには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/106/php%E3%81%A7%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E5%88%97%E3%81%8C%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%89%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%8B%E5%88%A4%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF/5068#5068)

▼JavaでのMXレコードを用いたメールサーバー判定
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0452.html

＜質問＞
クライアントサイドでドメインチェックをする方法がありましたらご教授いただけますでしょうか？
（初心者で実現性など加味できていないかと思います、、）
バッチ処理などでメールドメイン名を蓄えておいて、それと入力メールドメインを照らしあわせるなど、妥協案でも構いませんのでご助言を頂ければ助かります！

Comment: さらに調べてみたのですが、Javaのプログラムでサーバー側でMXレコードをチェックする機能を用意しておき、そのプログラムをAjaxやNode.js（？）などで画面遷移なしに利用するということが出来るのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

> クライアントサイドでドメインチェックをする方法がありましたらご教授いただけますでしょうか？

メールアドレスのドメインの存在をチェックするには DNS に問い合わせるのが良いと思いますが、DNSクエリはクライアントサイドでは出来ないと思います。サーバーサイドで機能を実装してクライアントサイドのJSから呼び出すことを考えたほうが良いと思います。

また、そもそも論として ドメインの存在をチェックしても、メールアドレスの存在確認にはなりません。突き詰めると 送信してみないことには判断付かない事が多いですので、間違ったメールアドレスを入力した場合は 会員登録することが出来ないようにするなどの対策を検討した方が賢明かも知れません。

Comment: やはりクライアントサイドだけで簡潔することは出来ないですよね、、
今回はメールドメインが存在するかだけの確認なので、メール送信まではしない予定です。
なので、”サーバーサイドで機能を実装してクライアントサイドのJSから呼び出す”で対応しようと思います。
ご助言ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0):

「ドメインが存在しているか」の定義を示されていないので、私はでたらめなドメインでないことを確認したい意図と解釈して、whoisを照会することとしました。jsonpでhttps://www.whoisxmlapi.com/のwhois照会サービスを利用します。[参考](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435678/whois-with-javascript)

```js
var baseURL = 'https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?';

var checkDomain = function (domain, callback) {
  var callback = callback || function () {},
      callbackName = '__checkDomain_jsonp_callback_' + Date.now();
  window[callbackName] = function (data) {
    callback(null, data.WhoisRecord);
  };
  var jsonpElement = document.createElement('script');
  jsonpElement.src = baseURL + 'outputFormat=json&domainName='
    + encodeURIComponent(domain) + '&callback=' + callbackName;
  jsonpElement.onerror = function (err) {
   callback(err);
  };
  document.body.appendChild(jsonpElement);
};

// example
checkDomain('example.com', function (err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
  if (data.dataError) {
   // たぶんこのプロパティがあるとwhoisが見当たらない→利用不可
  }
});
checkDomain('example-not-exists-not-available.com', function (err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
  if (data.dataError) {
   // たぶんこのプロパティがあるとwhoisが見当たらない→利用不可
  }
});
```

ここまで書いて、コメントを見て気付きましたが、DNSのMXレコードをチェックしたほうが確実かもしれませんね。そちらもhttpリクエストで利用できるサービスがあれば、同様にしてできると思いますし、コメントにあるように自前でhttpリクエストを受け付けるサーバーサイドのプログラムを用意してもいいかもしれません。

Comment: ご助言ありがとうございます！
Whoisというサービス初めて聞きました。
実装しなくても便利なサービスが用意されているのですね、参考になりました。